# Long tag names don't display properly

Tags: bug, estado-rechazado, etiquetas

In [an answer to another meta question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/132/54), I made an example of a long tag name that didn't render properly:

[request-to-translate-three-words-from-english-to-spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/request-to-translate-three-words-from-english-to-spanish)

I tried doing this on StackOverflow and didn't see this behavior (the image stopped appearing after a certain length), so I think this is a bug on the beta SE sites.

Comment: Note that the "bug" here is only in the rendering of that post. You can't actually *create* a tag that long. Tags are limited to 25 characters.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Oh ok. I didn't try to actually create it, for obvious reasons :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an honest case, this is really more of a "Don't do that" kind of scenario. There is a limit of <s>25</s> [35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/209901) on a real tag, and trying to use any longer to illustrate a point becomes ineffective. Your example then becomes invalid for reasons other than the point you intend to illustrate.

If you want to focus *on* the fact that a tag name would end up too long, saying it is too long would be a wiser course of action than using knowingly-going-to-never-work-as-a-link tag syntax.

This is, for now, just a very low priority bug.

Comment: Agreed. My point was just that this happens on the beta sites and not on the launched sites (as far as I can tell).